# Specifiying URL or URLRoot property - backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, appcelerator

```
exports.definition = {

    config : {
        // table schema and adapter information
    },

    extendModel: function(Model) {      
        _.extend(Model.prototype, {
            // Extend, override or implement the Backbone.Model methods                     
        });
        return Model;
    },

    extendCollection: function(Collection) {        
        _.extend(Collection.prototype, {

            // Implement the comparator method.
            comparator : function(book) {
                return book.get('title');
            }

        }); // end extend

        return Collection;
    }
}
```

Where should i specify url property to communicate with my rest service.

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_Models

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
exports.definition = {
    config: {
            "columns": {
                "username": "",
                "password": ""
            },
            "defaults": {
                "username": "-",
                "password": "-"
            },
            "adapter": {
                "type": "restapi",
                "collection_name": "user"
            }
        },

    extendModel: function(Model) {      
        _.extend(Model.prototype, {
            **urlRoot**:'',
            checkLogin: function(){

            } 
        });

        return Model;
    },

    extendCollection: function(Collection) {        
        _.extend(Collection.prototype, {
            // Extend, override or implement Backbone.Collection 
        });

        return Collection;
    }
}
```

Backbone.sync method executes RESTful JSON requests to a URL specified by the Model.urlRoot or Collection.url attribute, when these classes are created. You can either specify in the `Model or Collection`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know about appcelerator, but in backbone you add url configuration in Collection, check [here](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-url)

Answer (score 0):

Well i'm not sure how to do that in Appcelerator but Backbone only solutions is that you need to pass a url option to your model or collection.

First you need to create your Backbone Models define the url (urlRoot for collection) and then extend them in your Appcelerator Models.

Here is the explanation from the titanium docs.

> "Since Backbone's primary use is for web applications, by default, the
>   Backbone.sync method executes RESTful JSON requests to a URL specified
>   by the Model.urlRoot or Collection.url attribute, when these classes
>   are created. "